# Why I am getting Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888, everytime I am running spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

Is it a bug? I followed this [Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/829). Is there any work-around....my Stack-Trace is below

```
Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
BeanFactory id=691d8d29-ed5e-3599-85d5-3143f172a939
Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e56f3e25] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1894122] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Comment: Please add the POM file to the question.

Comment: Because you have `spring-cloud-config` as a dependency.